# Issues with generating AAR library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-glide, aar

I have an android project that I want to convert into an .aar library. Inside this project, I am using some google libraries as well as my own SDK library as an aar. Here is the `build.gradle` below.

I want the Google library to be included in the final aar, but exclude my own SDK library, so I choose `implementation` and `compileOnly` keywords for them respectively. When I compile, the code compiles successfully, but when I generate the .aar file and when I include it in another project, it doesn't have the Google library included for some reasons and throws this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/....
```

So I have to manually add it again in the new project via `implementation <google library>`.

Is there anything I should do to generate a correct .aar library that includes the Google library but excludes my SDK library? My intention is to create a separate .aar file for this project and include it as a plugin alongside with my SDK.

```
plugins {
    //id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.android.library'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.sample'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "com.example.sample" //remove for library
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    // Google library
    compileOnly 'com.google.somelibrary:1.0.0' //should be included in aar
    compileOnly files('libs/mysdk.aar') //should NOT be included in aar
}
```